# Best way to style SVG without having them inline

Tags: html, css, svg, css-selectors

I have a menu with about 10 items. Each item has its own icon. This icon is a SVG file.

For example:

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="/home">
        <svg version="1.1" id="svg-menu-home"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
             x="0px" y="0px" width="31px" height="31px" viewBox="-8 -8 31 31"
             overflow="visible" enable-background="new -8 -8 31 31" xml:space="preserve">
            <mask maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="15" height="15" id="maskTop">
                <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="12,6.036 2,6.036 2,14.036 6,14.036 6,9.036 8,9.036 8,14.036 12,14.036"/>
                <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="7,0.036 0,7.036 14,7.036"/>
            </mask>
            <rect mask="url(#maskTop)" fill="#939598" width="15" height="15"/>
        </svg>
        <span>Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

When a user interacts with the menu item I can assign a class etc to it (hover, select, active).

Having the entire source inline seems to be the only way I can change SVG using CSS, such as:

```
<style>
    li.active svg polygon {
       fill: red;
    }
</style>
```

The problem is:

1. Having any significant number of SVG files inline makes code unreadable, and
2. Doesn't make it easy to maintain the SVG if you reference it elsewhere.

I would much rather make reference to the file *src* the way you would an IMG (`<img src="x.jpg"/>`) and avoid a Javascript dependent solution.

However all the ways I've seen don't allow for CSS styling of the SVG element (or require JS).

Any thoughts/workarounds?

Comment: Did you heard about xml-stylesheet?

Comment: Selectors can't reach inner DOMs, meaning you can't link to an external SVG and have a selector find any element within that SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but you could organize them into php includes:

```
<?php include 'inc/svg-menu-home.svg.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is not a bad way to have a look over http://raphaeljs.com/ . It helped me to create this http://screencast.com/t/rNr0Cbqkb ( every area is a svg )